# Spring security no password

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to have a login form in my Spring MVC/ Hibernate app, where users can login with only a valid username, (no password) is required. I am currently using Spring Security but it required a user name and password, so I was wondering if it is possible to allow login with no password? and if yes how? Any sample, link to tutorial/ example is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do it with

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

null here is password, but not required.